# SettingWithCopyWarning while filtering rows that are <= than float

Tags: python, pandas, csv

`sencap.csv` is a file that has a lot of columns that I don't need and I want to keep just some columns in order to start filtering it to analyze the information and do some graphs, which in this case it'll be a pie chart that aggregate energy quantities depending on its energy source. Everything works fine except the condition that asks to `sum()` only those rows which are less than 9.0 MW.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aux = pd.read_csv('sencap.csv')

keep_col = ['subsistema','propietario','razon_social', 'estado',
            'fecha_servicio_central', 'region_nombre', 'comuna_nombre',
            'tipo_final', 'clasificacion', 'tipo_energia', 'potencia_neta_mw',
            'ley_ernc', 'medio_generacion', 'distribuidora', 'punto_conexion',
            ]
c1 = aux['medio_generacion'] == 'PMGD'
c2 = aux['medio_generacion'] == 'PMG'

aux2 = aux[keep_col]
aux3 = aux2[c1 | c2]

for col in ['potencia_neta_mw']:
    aux3[col] = pd.to_numeric(aux3[col].str.replace(',','.'))

c3 = aux3['potencia_neta_mw'] <= 9.0
aux4 = aux3[c3]

df = aux4.groupby(['tipo_final']).sum()
```

Warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>
> `aux3[col] = pd.to_numeric(aux3[col].str.replace(',','.'))`

Comment: Not sure what is your question but `aux2` is a copy of `aux`, that's why the warning is thrown. If you change `aux2`, `aux` will remain the same

Comment: what is wrong then with df? what's the result you get?

Comment: @Yuca I'm sorry. I added the entire warning now.

Comment: @Zrakk is your question about the warning you are getting.

Comment: @user6924051 yes it is. My final dataframe shows exactly what I want but that warning have me the idea of doing something in an inefficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aux3[col] = pd.to_numeric(aux3[col].str.replace(',','.'))
```

this line is the reason you are getting a warning.

Accessing the "col" using indexing may result in unpredictable behavior since it may return view or copy of original data.

it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees

pandas documentation advises users to use .loc instead.

Example:

```
In: df

Out: 
      one          two       
  first second first second
0     a      b     c      d
1     e      f     g      h
2     i      j     k      l
3     m      n     o      p

dfmi.loc[:,('one','second')] = value
# becomes
dfmi.loc.__setitem__((slice(None), ('one', 'second')), value)

dfmi['one']['second'] = value
# becomes
dfmi.__getitem__('one').__setitem__('second', value)
```

In the second case __getitem__ is unpredictable. It may return view or copy of the data. Modifying a view and copy works differently.

Making change on copy is not reflected on the original data where as a change on a view does.

**Note**: So the warning is present to warn users, even if you get the expected output there is a chance it might causes some unpredictable behavior.